# Check if Price Column has value in Lacs or Crore, then convert the value to actual number

Tags: python

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price' : ['5.5 lacs', '5.7 Crore', '3.5 lacs', '3.15 lacs']})
```

5.5 lacs will become 550000 and 5.7 Crore will become 57000000.

Then Save these new values in the same column Price at the corresponding places.

I know to change one of them at a time i.e values in lac.

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.strip('lacs')

df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'])

df['Price'] = df['Price'] * 100000

df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(int)
```

But do not know how to check if value is in lac or crore and even if find it out, i do not how to convert the values and save back in the column. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
arr = ['5.5 lacs', '5.7 Crore', '3.5 lacs', '3.15 lacs']
new = list(map(lambda x: (
            denom := x.find('lacs'),
            float(x[:denom].strip(" "))*100000 if denom!=-1 else float(x[:x.find('Crore')].strip(" "))*10000000
        ), arr))

new = list(map(lambda x : x[1], new))
```

The following code uses lambdas to solve the problem, (please take care of accessing Panda dataframes yourself, this approach should carry over).

##### Explanation

Lacs is 10^5 and Crores is 10^7

1. `list(map(lambda x:` we map a lambda function for each element in the list.
2. `denom := x.find('lacs')`: find if the denomination is in lacs (returns -1 if not present)
3. `float(x[:denom].strip(" "))*100000 if denom!=-1 else float(x[:x.find('Crore')].strip(" "))*10000000` using string splicing we extract the number, removes the spaces using strip, cast to float and then multiply with the factor depending on the denomination. This will run on every array element.
4. `new = list(map(lambda x : x[1], new))` The returned list will be a `[(denom, new_value)]` the following line yields a list `[new_value]`

##### Test

```
Input: ['5.5 lacs', '5.7 Crore', '3.5 lacs', '3.15 lacs']
Output: [550000.0, 57000000.0, 350000.0, 315000.0]
```

You can probably get rid of the first value by not creating a temp variable in the lambda and just replacing denom with `x.find('lacs')` but I've included it for explanations' sake.